# RouteData There is no argument given that responds to the required param of pageType of RouteData.RouteData(Type, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object?>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, syntax-error, routedata

How do I instantiate the RouteData object in C# ASP.NET MVC Core (.NET 8.0). I'm trying to use it to unit test a controller, but I keep receiving the following error as I'm missing the parameters that go into the constructor, when I instantiate the object.

The error is:

> There is no argument given that responds to the required parameter of
> pageType of 'RouteData.RouteData(Type, IReadOnlyDictionary<string,
> object?>)'